# Commons VFS fails for different file extension

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

I am new to Commons VFS and am trying to understand how to open a nested archive.  I found an example in the source code that deals with this.  This test passes.

```
@Test
void testTGZ() throws Exception {
    FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
        
    String uri = "tgz:file:///c:/data/nested.tgz!/test.tgz";

    FileObject archive = fsManager.resolveFile(uri);

    FileObject nestedFs = fsManager.createFileSystem(archive);
    // List the children of the archive file
    FileObject[] children = nestedFs.getChildren();
    for (FileObject child : children) {
        System.out.println(child.getURI());
    }
}
```

whereas this one fails with

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not find a file provider that can handle file "tgz:file:///C:/data/nested.tar.gz!/test.tar.gz".
```

```
@Test
void testTarGZ() throws Exception {
    FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();

    String uri = "tgz:file:///c:/data/nested.tar.gz!/test.tar.gz";

    FileObject archive = fsManager.resolveFile(uri);

    FileObject nestedFs = fsManager.createFileSystem(archive);
    // List the children of the archive file
    FileObject[] children = nestedFs.getChildren();
    for (FileObject child : children) {
        System.out.println(child.getURI());
    }
}
```

Other than the names the files are the same so why would one work and not the other?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How were the two files created? A file created with `tar zcf foo.tgz inputfilenames` will not be the same as one created with `tar cf foo.tar inputfilenames; gzip foo.tar`.  Could it be that Commons VFS handles one but not the other?

Comment: @JimGarrison you may be right. I will have to check into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same issue and after debugging I was able to find the source of the problem.

If you take a look at `createFileSystem(FileObject file)` in the `DefaultFileSystemManager` class, you can find that it uses the method `getScheme(FileObject file)` from the `FileTypeMap` class to detect the scheme:

```java
/**
 * Find the scheme for the provider of a layered file system.
 * <p>
 * This will check the FileContentInfo or file extension.
 * </p>
 *
 * @return Scheme supporting the file type or null (if unknown).
 */
public String getScheme(final FileObject file) throws FileSystemException {
    // Check the file's mime type for a match
    final FileContent content = file.getContent();
    final String mimeType = content.getContentInfo().getContentType();
    if (mimeType != null) {
        return mimeTypeMap.get(mimeType);
    }

    // no specific mime-type - if it is a file also check the extension
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        return null; // VFS-490 folders don't use extensions for mime-type
    }
    final String extension = file.getName().getExtension();
    return extensionMap.get(extension);
}
```

When the extension is `tgz`, `mimeType` is evaluated to `null` and the method tries to get the scheme using the extension itself. In this case, `tgz` is returned from `extensionMap` and `DefaultFileSystemManager` uses that value to select a `FileProvider` (`TarFileProvider` in this case).

When the extension is `tar.gz`, `mimeType` is parsed as `application/octet-stream` which doesn't have any mapping in `mimeTypeMap` and the methods returns `null`. In this case, `DefaultFileSystemManager` fails to create a file system because no `FileProvider` was found.

*Solution*:

You can specify the `FileProvider` while creating the file system:

```java
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();

// tgz file
String tgz = "file:/C:/data/nested.tgz";
FileObject tgzFileObject = manager.resolveFile(tgz);
FileObject tgzFileSystem = manager.createFileSystem("tgz", tgzFileObject);

// tar.gz file
String targz = "file:/C:/data/nested.tar.gz";
FileObject targzFileObject = manager.resolveFile(targz);
FileObject targzFileSystem = manager.createFileSystem("tgz", targzFileObject);
```